# Access to the path '...\email@gmail.coml.jpg' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hosted an ASPX website which contains a registration page. When I am trying to upload the image it is showing the following error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\example.org\httpdocs\Alumni\uploadimage\email@gmail.coml.jpg' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

I have given full read, write, modify all permission to the folder. Below is the coding which i have used.

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//uploadimage//" + str);
string path = "../Alumni/uploadimage/" + str.ToString();
```

Comment: "I have given full read, write, modify all permission to the folder." ... Evidently you haven't. I'd think really hard about whether writing to your web root is really what you need to do...

Comment: what user account / identity is your webapp running under?

Comment: And if my email is `../../../` I can write to the C:\ folder of your server? Cool!